# Is it possible to use route parameters for the default controller in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm having quite a few bundles whose routing rules I don't want to include by hand in my main routing.yml, so I'm looking for a way to define a route that is then forwarded to a controller depending on the parameters in the url.

Something like this in my routing.yml:

```
foo_main:
    path:   /foo/{bundle}/{action}
    defaults: { _controller: "Foo{bundle}Bundle:Api:{action}" }
```

It should behave like this:

`/foo/acme/index` -> `FooAcmeBundle:Api:indexAction`
`/foo/bar/show` -> `FooBarBundle:Api:showAction`
...

I already saw there is a custom route provider that could automatically register new routes, if the above is not possible. But I guess I have to add a custom route provider to each bundle, which seems like a unnecessary overhead if each bundle registers its route the same way.

PS: I'm using Symfony 2.3.1 right now.

Comment: Ok, it seems it's not possible and has been asked before: [Convention-based routing in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677330/convention-based-routing-in-symfony2)

Comment: actually it is possible , please see my answer - comment if anything unclear :)

Comment: Thanks, actually there is really is something unclear ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FOSRestBundle's [automatic route generation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md).

It does not include the bundle-name in the route but you could abuse the @RouteResource annotation to match your bundle name.

An example can be found in the docs under [Implicit resource name definition](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition) (2nd codeblock).

Comment: nfir, thanks for your comment. I'm not quite sure if I fully understood it. Could you please give an example that suites my question?