# Symfony2 / routing / use parameters as Controller or Action name

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

Is it possible to route to a controller/action using given parameters ?

For example :

```
my_custom_route:
    pattern: /{controller}/{action}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:[controller]:[action] }
```

I would like [controller] and [action] to be replaced by given route's parameters values.

I.E : `http://www.somedomain.com/Content/add` should call action "**addAction**" of controller "**ContentController**" in bundle "AcmeDemoBundle"

Comment: Why would you do that? It sounds like an ugly hack. If you're too lazy to type all the routes in yml, I advise you to switch to annotations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convention-based routing in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677330/convention-based-routing-in-symfony2)

Comment: You could create a controller which takes a controller and action and executes that action, but you shouldn't: it's a bad practice

Comment: When you create a backend (admin) application for a web site, you always (I think...) have the same operations to do with different tables : **add** new row, **update** existing one and **delete** one. May be "I'm too lazy to type all the routes in yml" ;-)

Comment: @jzpululu Yes, that's called [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) and you have a symfony command to generate these easily. `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so however it is not recommended. What would you do in future of you had to refactor your code and your controller / action had to change? You may break links and functionality along with possibly losing search engine optimization that may have been done for that particular route.

Comment: It's an excellent idea, if the first default controller routing does not work.. then it goes and finds one self declared that does! If you need to change it in the future, just change it.. So if you cannot do it, then do you know of a tool or framework that does apart from just using htaccess... This is a common requirement, I have 1000 odd pages that all use the same routing Controller/Action, why on EARTH do I have to declare every bloody one.. There should be a common routing! like C#.NET MVC 4.0. Looking forward to the answer