# Defining default routing for controller/action in symfony 2

Tags: php, url, symfony, controller, routes

If I wanted to make it so that every url call apart from ones I have defined after act upon **/ExplicitControllerName/ExplicitActionToRun**... how might the routing look like.

for example some pseudo code:

```
default_pathing:
    pattern:  /{controller}/{action}
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Default:index }
```

So if I went to 
**www.example.com/Page/About**

it would call my controller

```
class Page extends Controller
{
    public AboutAction()
    {
        // Called by above URL
    }
}
```

This question does not answer: [Symfony2 / routing / use parameters as Controller or Action name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595027/symfony2-routing-use-parameters-as-controller-or-action-name)

Imagine I have 100 pages with lots of sub routing pages doing pretty much the same routing every time. I want to do 1 routing for all those 100 controllers. How would we do this?

P.S I'm really going for something like the C#.NET MVC 4.0 routing in which it allows you to set a routing for a typical setup you might have even if at the very least its for development

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not totally clear but here are some hints.

I can imagine two use cases you're trying to solve:

1) You've a lot of some sort of CMS page, like your about example, these pages don't have much logic and just render some view, in such case you would something like:

```
class CMSPageController
{
    public function renderPage($pageSlug)
    {
        $page = $this->cmsPageRepository->findBySlug($pageSlug);

        // your logic to render the view
    }
}
```

And the according routing configuration:

```
<route id="cms_page_view" pattern="/cms/{pageSlug}">
  <default key="_controller">cms_page.controller.page:renderPage</default>
  <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
  <requirement key="slug">[0-9a-zA-Z\-\.\/]+</requirement>
</route>
```

2) You have much more complex requirements, and/or follow a specific pattern to name your controller/action, therefore you need to write a custom [`UrlMatcherInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcherInterface.html) implementation. Take a look at the [native implementation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L124) to know where to start. It would allow you define a fallback.

Comment: Its a good solution, but you also need to keep the lid on that can of worms, because when you have a catch all controller, its essentially impossible for a 404 exception to occur, unless your controller is very precise.

Comment: Flosculus, that's right but I assumed the OP was aware of such behavior, by the way we could imagine a router which matches page from a database and return a 404 if no matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using either SensioFrameworkExtraBundle's [@Route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix) annotation on class- and method-level excessively...

... or more elegant with less annotations using FOSRestBundle's [automatic route generation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition) with implicit resource names. Maybe you'll need to correct some of the generated routes using some of FOSRestBundle's [manual route definition annotations](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/7-manual-route-definition.md).

Both methods originally still leave the need to explicitly add the route resources to your `app/config/routing.yml`.

Example import for @Route

```
# import routes from a controller directory
blog:
    resource: "@SensioBlogBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

Example import for FOSRestBundle

```
users:
    type:     rest
    resource: Acme\HelloBundle\Controller\UsersController
```

You could work around having to import all the resources by:

- introducing a [custom annotation](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/) (class-level)
- creating a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) or a [custom route loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) in which you ...
- use the [Finder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) to find all controller classes in all bundles with that annotation
- finally add all those as resources with type annotation/rest to the route collection in there

If you don't plan to use hundreds of controllers and don't have too much experience with compiler-passes, custom annotations, ... etc. you'll definitely be faster just registering the resources in the routing config.